# OnClickListener Error?

Tags: android, onclicklistener

I'm building a program using some buttons. Everything is perfect and beautiful until this error popped up.

[image: onclicklistener error]

I tried as much ways as possible but it still doesn't work! Can you explain the error and the way to fix it? Here is my code:

```
package com.huy9515gmail.mycontact;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import butterknife.BindView;
import butterknife.ButterKnife;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
@BindView(R.id.edt_inputName) EditText edtName;
@BindView(R.id.btnAdd) Button btnAdd;
@BindView(R.id.edt_inputNumber) EditText edtNumber;
@BindView(R.id.rdbtn_male) RadioButton rdbtn_male;
@BindView(R.id.rdbtn_female) RadioButton rdbtn_female;
@BindView(R.id.rdbtn_others) RadioButton rdbtn_others;
@BindView(R.id.gender) RadioGroup genderSelection;
private ListView lvContact;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);

    lvContact = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv_contact);
    final ArrayList<Contact> arrContact = new ArrayList<>();

    btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onclick(View v) {
            //validating contact info
            if (((edtName.getText().toString().trim()) == "") || (edtNumber.getText().toString().trim() == "")) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Invalid contact info! Please try again!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            //adding contact info
            else {
                Contact contact = new Contact(Gender.male, "", "");

                //receiving gender
                boolean isMale, isFemale, isOthers;
                if (rdbtn_male.isChecked()) contact.setGender(Gender.male);
                if (rdbtn_female.isChecked()) contact.setGender(Gender.female);
                if (rdbtn_others.isChecked()) contact.setGender(Gender.others);

                //adding info
                contact.setName(edtName.getText().toString());
                contact.setNumber(edtNumber.getText().toString());

                arrContact.add(contact);
            }
        }
    });

    CustomAdapter customAdapter = new CustomAdapter(this, R.layout.row_listview, arrContact);
    lvContact.setAdapter(customAdapter);
}
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace this line:

```
public void onclick(View v) {
```

With this (we just modified the capital C):

```
public void onClick(View v) {
```

---

It is a tricky thing, but since you're working with anonymous classes, you need to override the exact signature that the interface is giving you, and it's case-sensitive.

The implementation of the [View.OnClickListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnClickListener.html) interface, requires you to implement the `onClick` method which receives one argument of type `View`.

Comment: Okay it's case-sensitive :v
I wonder why this error sometimes popped up and sometimes not, so that's the reason :v
Thanks for your help! <3 Now I can complete my program :D

Answer (score 1):

Try to add @Override annotation if your Activity implements OnClickListener interface

And make the `C` capital like this:

```
btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //your codes

            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for your help :D Now I can complete my program <3

Answer (score 0):

You need to do exactly what the error is telling you to do.

You have to override the onClick method.

```
btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //validating contact info
        if (((edtName.getText().toString().trim()) == "") || (edtNumber.getText().toString().trim() == "")) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Invalid contact info! Please try again!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        //adding contact info
        else {
            Contact contact = new Contact(Gender.male, "", "");

            //receiving gender
            boolean isMale, isFemale, isOthers;
            if (rdbtn_male.isChecked()) contact.setGender(Gender.male);
            if (rdbtn_female.isChecked()) contact.setGender(Gender.female);
            if (rdbtn_others.isChecked()) contact.setGender(Gender.others);

            //adding info
            contact.setName(edtName.getText().toString());
            contact.setNumber(edtNumber.getText().toString());

            arrContact.add(contact);
        }
    }
});
```